# O_RDWR on named pipes with poll()

Tags: linux, ipc, pipe, mkfifo

I have gone through a variaty of different linux named pipe client/server implementations but most of them use the blocking defaults on reads/writes.

As I am already using poll() to check other flags I though it would be a good idea to check for incoming FIFO data via poll() as well...

After all the research I think that opening the pipe in O_RDWR mode is the only way to prevent an indefinitely number of EOF events on a pipe when no writer has opened it.

This way both ends of the pipe are closed and other clients can open the writable end as well. To respond back I would use separate pipes...

My problem is that although I have found some examples that use the O_RDWR flag the open() manpages describe this flag as being unefined when assigned to a FIFO. (http://linux.die.net/man/3/open)

But how would you use poll() on a pipe without O_RDWR? Do you think "O_RDWR" is a legitimate way to open pipes???

Comment: Did you read `mkfifo(3)` and `fifo(7)` man pages? And you won't get an indefinite number of EOF events.... Can't you open it `O_RDONLY` on one side, and `O_WRONLY` on the other side (and rthen `poll` appropriately)? And `fifo(7)` explicitly says that *"opening  a  FIFO for read and write will succeed both in
       blocking and nonblocking mode"*

Comment: Yeah you are right fifo(7) mentions it to be OK under Linux (although it is no standardized POSIX behavior). 

The thing here is that I cannot open the reading end with "O_RDONLY" only and the writing end with "O_WRONLY" because by default this will block and that is not allowed in my use case.

So while I can theoretically open it with O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCKING it will not block but since there might be no writer EOF events will be thrown on poll().

So I will have to go with O_RDWR to avoid blocking behavior on open() and to be able to use poll()...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First, some preliminaries:

Using `O_NONBLOCK` and `poll()` is common practice -- not the other way around. To work successfully, you need to be sure to handle all `poll()` and `read()` return states correctly:

- `read()` return value of `0` means EOF -- the other side has closed its connection. This corresponds (usually, but not on all OSes) to `poll()` returning a `POLLHUP` revent. You may want to check for `POLLHUP` before attempting `read()`, but it is not absolutely necessary since `read()` is guaranteed to return `0` after the writing side has closed.
- If you call `read()` before a writer has connected, and you have `O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK`, you will get EOF (`read()` returning `0`) repeatedly, as you've noticed. However, if you use `poll()` to wait for a `POLLIN` event before calling `read()`, it will wait for the writer to connect, and not produce the EOFs.
- `read()` return value `-1` usually means error. However, if `errno == EAGAIN`, this simply means there is no more data available right now and you're not blocking, so you can go back to `poll()` in case other devices need handling. If `errno == EINTR`, then `read()` was interrupted before reading any data, and you can either go back to `poll()` or simply call `read()` again immediately.

Now, for Linux:

- If you open on the reading side with `O_RDONLY`, then:

  - The `open()` will block until there is a corresponding writer open.
  - `poll()` will give a `POLLIN` revent when data is ready to be read, or EOF occurs.
  - `read()` will block until either the requested number of bytes is read, the connection is closed (returns 0), it is interrupted by a signal, or some fatal IO error occurs. This blocking sort of defeats the purpose of using `poll()`, which is why `poll()` almost always is used with `O_NONBLOCK`. You could use an `alarm()` to wake up out of `read()` after a timeout, but that's overly complicated.
  - If the writer closes, then the reader will receive a `poll()` `POLLHUP` revent and `read()` will return `0` indefinitely afterwards. At this point, the reader must close its filehandle and reopen it.
- If you open on the reading side with `O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK`, then:

  - The `open()` will not block.
  - `poll()` will give a `POLLIN` revent when data is ready to be read, or EOF occurs. `poll()` will also block until a writer is available, if none is present.
  - After all currently available data is read, `read()` will either return -1 and set `errno == EAGAIN` if the connection is still open, or it will return `0` if the connection is closed (EOF) *or not yet opened by a writer*. When `errno == EAGAIN`, this means it's time to return to `poll()`, since the connection is open but there is no more data. When `errno == EINTR`, `read()` has read no bytes yet and was interrupted by a signal, so it can be restarted.
  - If the writer closes, then the reader will receive a `poll()` `POLLHUP` revent, and `read()` will return `0` indefinitely afterwards. At this point the reader must close its filehandle and reopen it.
- (Linux-specific:) If you open on the reading side with `O_RDWR`, then:

  - The `open()` will not block.
  - `poll()` will give a `POLLIN` revent when data is ready to be read. However, for named pipes, EOF will not cause `POLLIN` or `POLLHUP` revents.
  - `read()` will block until the requested number of bytes is read, it is interrupted by a signal, or some other fatal IO error occurs. For named pipes, it will not return `errno == EAGAIN`, nor will it even return `0` on EOF. It will just sit there until the exact number of bytes requested is read, or until it receives a signal (in which case it will return the number of bytes read so far, or return -1 and set `errno == EINTR` if no bytes were read so far).
  - If the writer closes, the reader will not lose the ability to read the named pipe later if another writer opens the named pipe, but the reader will not receive any notification either.
- (Linux-specific:) If you open on the reading side with `O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK`, then:

  - The `open()` will not block.
  - `poll()` will give a `POLLIN` revent when data is ready to be read. However, EOF will not cause `POLLIN` or `POLLHUP` revents on named pipes.
  - After all currently available data is read, `read()` will return `-1` and set `errno == EAGAIN`. This is the time to return to `poll()` to wait for more data, possibly from other streams.
  - If the writer closes, the reader will not lose the ability to read the named pipe later if another writer opens the named pipe. The connection is persistent.

As you are rightly concerned, using `O_RDWR` with pipes is not standard, POSIX or elsewhere.

However, since this question seems to come up often, the best way on Linux to make "resilient named pipes" which stay alive even when one side closes, and which don't cause `POLLHUP` revents or return `0` for `read()`, is to use `O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK`.

I see three main ways of handling named pipes on Linux:

1. (Portable.) Without `poll()`, and with a single pipe:

   - `open(pipe, O_RDONLY);`
   - Main loop:

     - `read()` as much data as needed, possibly looping on `read()` calls.

       - If `read() == -1` and `errno == EINTR`, `read()` all over again.
       - If `read() == 0`, the connection is closed, and all data has been received.
2. (Portable.) With `poll()`, and with the expectation that pipes, even named ones, are only opened once, and that once they are closed, must be reopened by both reader and writer, setting up a new pipeline:

   - `open(pipe, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);`
   - Main loop:

     - `poll()` for `POLLIN` events, possibly on multiple pipes at once. (Note: This prevents `read()` from getting multiple EOFs before a writer has connected.)
     - `read()` as much data as needed, possibly looping on `read()` calls.

       - If `read() == -1` and `errno == EAGAIN`, go back to `poll()` step.
       - If `read() == -1` and `errno == EINTR`, `read()` all over again.
       - If `read() == 0`, the connection is closed, and you must terminate, or close and reopen the pipe.
3. (Non-portable, Linux-specific.) With `poll()`, and with the expectation that named pipes never terminate, and may be connected and disconnected multiple times:

   - `open(pipe, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);`
   - Main loop:

     - `poll()` for `POLLIN` events, possibly on multiple pipes at once.
     - `read()` as much data as needed, possibly looping on `read()` calls.

       - If `read() == -1` and `errno == EAGAIN`, go back to `poll()` step.
       - If `read() == -1` and `errno == EINTR`, `read()` all over again.
       - If `read() == 0`, something is wrong -- it shouldn't happen with `O_RDWR` on named pipes, but only with `O_RDONLY` or unnamed pipes; it indicates a closed pipe which must be closed and re-opened. If you mix named and unnamed pipes in the same `poll()` event-handling loop, this case may still need to be handled.

Comment: (2.) Saved my day =) Thanks!

Comment: Terrific answer! This totally demystifies all the weird stuff about pipes

Answer (score 1):

According to [open(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html) man page, you can pass `O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK`  or `O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK` to avoid the `open` syscall to be blocked (you'll get `errno == ENXIO` in that case)

As I commented read also the [fifo(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/fifo.7.html) and [mkfifo(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html) man pages.

Comment: thanks but on linux, "O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK" will not work I guess...

The thing is that I cannot block on open AND want to use poll() so when I use O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK it will not block but poll() will fire EOF events all the time... So "O_NONBLOCK" and poll() is a bad combination.

So it seems that I have to go with O_RDWR although its no POSIX standard. So is there a way to use poll() on non blocking pipes without O_RDWR???

Comment: I never coded that, but the man page says that `O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK` should work without blocking. Did you tested it? Of course you cannot `poll` for `open` (since `poll` requires file descriptors returned by `open`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this for sure later.

I am not going to poll on open. I will use POLLIN on reads after I have successfully openend the pipe....

Answer (score 0):

Just keep an open O_WRONLY file descriptor in the reading process alongside the O_RDONLY one. This will achieve the same effect, ensuring that read() never returns end-of-file and that poll() and select() will block.

And it's 100% POSIX